What is the difference between Survey, SMS, and SLR
I wonder if there is actual difference among a survey, systematic mapping study, and a systematic literature review? All of them involve three main phases: specifying research questions and search string; conducting the literature search; and performing data analysis and documentation.
Context Domain: CS and software engineering

There is no "official" definition for any of these. While some people will have their own definitions, others will have contradictory definitions. In my opinion, the definitions do not really matter; what really matters is, what exactly do you want to do? What is your real task?

That said, one of the best articles that distinguishes different types of literature reviews is Paré et al. 2015 "Synthesizing information systems knowledge: A typology of literature reviews
": https://www-sciencedirect-com.skema.idm.oclc.org/science/article/pii/S0378720614001116?casa_token=zR0__rwDEQ0AAAAA:uZaXrmZRGGhkKTWISSKOuoS4B5FmQjjMoqUiOHWXxVg0MXbA8Z8CSI8XG9dhhTStkQ0B1KAmMe4.  However, even that article does not use the same terminology that you use in your question. To me it matters more to understand what you're trying to do than to stick ambiguous labels on it.
